# No scraping with Facebook debugger

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, seo, facebook-opengraph

**EDIT : the issue was related to the inability from Facebook to scrape the website.**

Here's the website : https://www.mydomain.fr. I have built a header with as many SEO-friendly elements as possible but Facebook give me error message I can't manage to fix.

The header is the following:

```
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/+mydomain"/>
<link rel="image_src" href="https://www.mydomain.fr/img/home-feature-bg.png" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="mydomain - Cures Detox Bio - Pression à froid"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mydomain"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.mydomain.fr/img/home-feature-bg.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.mydomain.fr/img/home-feature-bg.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mydomain.fr/"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="mydomain"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="mydomain"/>
<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="mydomain" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="mydomain" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="mydomain" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.mydomain.fr/img/home-feature-bg.png" />
<meta name="twitter:site" value="https://www.mydomain.fr" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" value="mydomain" />
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "https://www.mydomain.fr",
  "logo": "https://www.mydomain.fr/img/mydomain-logo.png"
}
</script>
<meta name="author" content="mydomain">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1" />
```

I don't understand why Facebook would say I don't have valid string for og:title and I don't understand the SSL error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have read a ton a posts on that issue and I finally found what was a common problem with the Facebook debugger.

1. Facebook was scraping no data
2. There was a AAAA CNAME DNS for my domain (host -v-t any yourdomain.com or host -a yourdomain.com under OSX terminal)
3. I removed it and now it works fine